# how to get total no of working hours with date & time in MYSQL with reference to checkin & next day checkout time

Tags: php, mysql

Below table shows the checkin & checkout time of employee

employee_oid report_date report_time

```
 11     2014-12-01 08:02:31
 21     2014-12-01 08:13:04
 06     2014-12-01 08:13:04
 11     2014-12-02 18:03:41
 21     2014-12-02 16:36:02
 06     2014-12-03 16:36:02
 11     2014-12-04 08:02:31
 06     2014-12-04 08:36:02
 21     2014-12-02 08:36:02
 11     2014-12-04 16:34:20
 06     2014-12-05 08:36:02
 21     2014-12-05 08:50:50
```

Comment: How exactly can we identify the check-in and check-out time? All you have are three columns which show date and time that applies to three employees twice.

Comment: @mike I am fetching data from text file of thumb reader.In that there is no separate field of checkin & checkout based on min checkin time with date& max checkout time with date.

Comment: There needs to be a start time AND end time for the same employee in order to calculate the hour difference. Without this info properly defined, I don't think we can provide an answer. Try to convert your table you provided so that there is a column for check-in time and a column for check-out time.

Comment: I believe there is no way to modify the table since he is getting it from a thumb reader. It doesn't define checkin or checkout. Maybe the only real reference would be the assumption that the FIRST record of a user is he's checkin, and then make all calculations referenced from there.

Answer (score 0):

What's the algorithm of working hours? 
Supposing working hours equals checkout time minus checkin time, I've got this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  Emp_id,
  report_date,
  MIN(report_time) AS checkin_time,
  MAX(report_time) AS checkout_time,
  DATE_FORMAT (MAX(report_time) - MIN(report_time), '%h') AS working_hours
FROM
  report 
GROUP BY Emp_id;
```

But, it sucks when employees go to work again and again....

I'm wandering why the employees should checkout in next day. It's also confusing when I saw employee 06 who checked out after two days. 囧

Comment: Wouldn't that query just return the time difference between the FIRST time an employee checked in and the LAST time? What happens if you need a report for every work session?

Comment: If an employee checked in and out for a year you would be getting only the difference between the first and last time, with no regard for everything in between. You'd get time difference for a year!

Comment: @Clarence if I will go with this query the workinghours will be null

Comment: @helloworld, The question is pretty unclear. I just wanted to throw out a minnow to catch a whale.

Comment: @Shivaraj patil, could you show more data and explain the regular pattern of checking in and checking out times?

Comment: @Clarence Just check above I had updated the some data.As based on date with respect to minimum time will be checkin & date with maximum time will be checkout

Comment: @helloworld ..have you come out with solutions?

Comment: @Shivarajpatil According to the data, Are they working in evening shift? All checking in are during evening. and all checing out are during morning, aren't they?

Comment: @Clarence maybe you could come up with a way to identify checkin and checkout based on time of day. Use the morning time as checkin and the compare it to evening time the next day. Do they always work over the night, or do you have people who only work on a single day?

Comment: @helloworld ,@Clarence ..have you come out with solutions?

Comment: @Shivarajpatil this is not how stack overflow works. We are not here to work for you. Do some research of your own, and then ask a new question. What else have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

For night shift, I tried this SQL which might be helpful:

```
SELECT 
  a.`id` AS employ_id,
  ADDTIME(MIN(a.adjustedDateTime), '12:00:00') AS check_in_time,
  ADDTIME(MAX(a.adjustedDateTime), '12:00:00') AS check_out_time,
  TIMEDIFF(
    MAX(a.adjustedDateTime),
    MIN(a.adjustedDateTime)
  ) AS working_time,
  COUNT(0) AS report_times,
  DATE_FORMAT(a.adjustedDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') AS report_date
FROM
  (SELECT 
    `Emp_id` AS id,
    SUBTIME(
      CONCAT(report_date, ' ', report_time),
      '12:00:00'
    ) AS adjustedDateTime 
  FROM
    report) a 
GROUP BY a.`id`,
  DATE_FORMAT(a.adjustedDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d') 
ORDER BY a.`id`, report_date;
```

I used `SUBTIME` to make the report_time which in one shift be gathered into one day. Then group by the date. Thus got the result.

Comment: I am not getting the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('dbconn.php');
$q="select employee_oid, min(concat(report_date,' ',report_time)) as checkin, max(concat(report_date,' ',report_time)) as checkout from report_master where 1 group by employee_oid,report_date;";
$rec = mysql_query($q);
$k=0;
$i=0;
$previous_empid=0;
if(mysql_num_rows($rec) > 0)
{ 
$arr=$arr2 = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rec))

{
$employee_oid = $row['employee_oid'];
$minmumdate = $row['checkin'];
$maxdate = $row['checkout'];
$timestamp1 = strtotime($minmumdate);
$timestamp2 = strtotime($maxdate);
$hour = abs($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)/(60*60);

$arr[$employee_oid][] = array(
'hours'=>$hour
);

}
        //print_r($arr);
foreach($arr as $key=>$result){
//echo $key.'   key value';
$total_hours=0;
foreach($result as $key1=>$result1){
$total_hours= $total_hours + $result1['hours'];
}
if($total_hours>176) {
    $extra_hours = $total_hours - 176;
    $extra_wages = $extra_hours * 31.25;
                }
$arr2[$key][] = array(
    'total_hours'=>$total_hours,
    'extra_hours'=>$extra_hours,
    'extra_wages' =>$extra_wages
    );

}

print("<pre>");
print_r($arr2);
exit();
foreach($arr2 as  $key=>$result){
echo $key.' = > total_hours '.$result['total_hours'].' extra_hours '.$result['extra_hours'].' extra_wages '.$result['extra_wages'].'</br></br>';
            }
    }

?>
```

Comment: @helloworld Till now I tried with this code but still there is issues with it .

Answer (score 0):

I have this query:-

```
select DATE_FORMAT(yb_date, '%d') AS yb_date,'2' as roll,'asd' AS staff_name,CASE WHEN yb.yb_date> '5050-12-31' THEN '' WHEN yb.yb_date<'0' THEN '' WHEN yb.yb_date> CURDATE() THEN '' WHEN yb.day_status = 'Holiday' AND date(a.attend_date) IS NULL THEN 'H' WHEN date(a.attend_date) IS NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END AS status,CASE WHEN time(min(attend_date)) IS NULL THEN '00:00:00' ELSE time(min(attend_date)) END as in_time,CASE WHEN time(max(attend_date)) IS NULL THEN '00:00:00' ELSE time(max(attend_date)) END as out_time,CASE WHEN timediff(time(max(attend_date)),time(min(attend_date))) IS NULL THEN '00:00:00' ELSE timediff(time(max(attend_date)),time(min(attend_date))) END as duration from yearbook yb LEFT join attendance_essl a ON date(a.attend_date)=yb.yb_date AND a.emp_id='000012' where yb.yb_date between '2019-09-29' AND '2019-10-05' group by yb.yb_date,a.emp_id order by yb.yb_date ASC
```

Output is :-

```
yb_date
roll
staff_name
status
in_time
out_time
duration
29
2
asd
H
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
30
2
asd
A
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
01
2
asd
A
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
02
2
asd
P
17:10:03
17:10:03
00:00:00
03
2
asd
P
15:10:03
15:10:03
00:00:00
04
2
asd
P
06:10:03
18:10:03
12:00:00
05
2
asd
H
00:00:00
00:00:00
00:00:00
```

If I add night shift means how to get